# VBA - get first cell when comment cell is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have few sheet that i would like to read all comments from each sheet.
I managed to get the comments but what i could get is the first cell of the same row and column of the commented cell.( attached photo)

red - commented cell.

green - required cell value.

[image]

```
    Sub ShowCommentsAllSheets()
    'Update 20140508
    Dim commrange As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Set newWs = Application.Worksheets("CRs")
    newWs.Range("A1").Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("Sheet", "A", "Value", "Comment")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set commrange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
        If Not commrange Is Nothing Then
            i = newWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each rng In commrange
                i = i + 1
                newWs.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(ws.Name, rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Comment.Text)
            Next
        End If
        Set commrange = Nothing
    Next
    newWs.Cells.WrapText = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - If `newWS` isn't the ActiveSheet, then the `Rows.Count` will run on another sheet. You should (assuming you want to count the rows in `NewWS`) change the line to `i = newWs.Cells(newWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.  Are you able to get the Date cell? And want to see how to get the same row's cell, in Column B?

Comment: Is your code erroring or doing the wrong thing? @BruceWayne - agree it's good practice but does that actually matter given that each sheet has the same number of rows?

Comment: Yes exactly, I managed to get the Date cell and I would like to get the same row's cell.

Comment: @David you could use `Range([date cell])Offset(0,-5)`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just change this line?

```
newWs.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(ws.Name, rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Comment.Text, ws.Cells(rng.Row, 2))
```